# iOS4 book recommendation

Tags: objective-c, ios4

Hi
I already have a few Objective C specific books, but I need to ramp up very quickly on all the new features that IOS4 contains.

Can anyone share their recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff LaMarche's books are a great resource but are written from the perspective of iOS 3.  If you're completely new to iOS programming in general, I'd still recommend picking up his book and then taking a look at [his blog](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com), where he is constantly posting updated information.  You'll learn all about iOS development, and then you'll likely be able to teach yourself the few major new features of iOS 4.

Master the basics before moving on.  iOS 4's major enhancements were multitasking, document support, and iPad-specific interface elements.  LaMarche's books will be helpful to you, regardless of version.

Comment: +1 for Jeff LaMarche recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Beginning iPhone 4 Development: Exploring the iOS SDK --> [http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-iPhone-Development-Exploring-iOS/dp/143023024X/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1290354782&sr=1-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143023024X)

helped me very much and is currently 30% off ;)